# get random value from a PHP array, but make it unique

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to select a random value from a array, but keep it unique as long as possible.

For example if I'm selecting a value 4 times from a array of 4 elements, the selected value should be random, but different every time.

If I'm selecting it 10 times from the same array of 4 elements, then obviously some values will be duplicated.

I have this right now, but I still get duplicate values, even if the loop is running 4 times:

```
$arr = $arr_history = ('abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'qqq');

for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
  if(empty($arr_history)) $arr_history = $arr; 
  $selected = $arr_history[array_rand($arr_history, 1)];  
  unset($arr_history[$selected]); 
  // do something with $selected here...
}
```

Comment: On a side note, http://www.nsftools.com/misc/DilbertRandom.gif

Comment: Why don't you use `array_rand($arr_history, 4)` to get the array in a random order? This ensures the that you have 4 unique values. In the next iteration you get the array in a different order.

Comment: The statement `unset($arr_history[$selected]);` seems to treat `$arr_history` as an associative array, since `$selected` is the value, not the index. That doesn't solve the problem, though. Unsetting `$selected` is supposed to remove it from the array, which implies that by the time the loop s done, the array is empty. Was that your intention? (I don't think so)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You almost have it right. The problem was the `unset($arr_history[$selected]);` line. The value of `$selected` isn't a key but in fact a value so the unset wouldn't work.

To keep it the same as what you have up there:

```
<?php

$arr = $arr_history = array('abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'qqq');

for ( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
  // If the history array is empty, re-populate it.
  if ( empty($arr_history) )
    $arr_history = $arr;

  // Select a random key.
  $key = array_rand($arr_history, 1);

  // Save the record in $selected.
  $selected = $arr_history[$key];

  // Remove the key/pair from the array.
  unset($arr_history[$key]);

  // Echo the selected value.
  echo $selected . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or an example with a few less lines:

```
<?php

$arr = $arr_history = array('abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'qqq');

for ( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
  // If the history array is empty, re-populate it.
  if ( empty($arr_history) )
    $arr_history = $arr;

  // Randomize the array.
  array_rand($arr_history);

  // Select the last value from the array.
  $selected = array_pop($arr_history);

  // Echo the selected value.
  echo $selected . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks that seems to work, but it's weird that a array like this has keys. I thought that both key and value would be the same

Comment: @Alex - No, in fact, when you don't specify the keys, PHP assigns them numeric keys starting at 0. See the parameters section of [http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) for more information.

Comment: It's alway the same result, no random

Answer (score 7):

How about shuffling the array, and popping items off.

When `pop` returns `null`, reset the array.

```
$orig = array(..);
$temp = $orig;
shuffle( $temp );

function getNextValue()
{
  global $orig;
  global $temp;

  $val = array_pop( $temp );

  if (is_null($val))
  {
    $temp = $orig;
    shuffle( $temp );
    $val = getNextValue();
  }
  return $val;
}
```

Of course, you'll want to encapsulate this better, and do better checking, and other such things.

Answer (score 4):

http://codepad.org/sBMEsXJ1

```
<?php

    $array = array('abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'qqq');

    $numRandoms = 3;

    $final = array();

    $count = count($array);

    if ($count >= $numRandoms) {

        while (count($final) < $numRandoms) {

            $random = $array[rand(0, $count - 1)];

            if (!in_array($random, $final)) {

                array_push($final, $random);
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($final);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Php has a native function called `shuffle` which you could use to randomly order the elements in the array. So what about this?

```
$arr = ('abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'qqq');

$random = shuffle($arr);

foreach($random as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: `shuffle` actually returns a boolean and modifies the original array so you would want `foreach ($arr as $a)`

Answer (score 2):

key != value, use this:

```
$index = array_rand($arr_history, 1);
$selected = $arr_history[$index];  
unset($arr_history[$index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this to create a random 8 digit password for users:

```
$characters = array(
    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M",
    "N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
    "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","m",
    "n","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
    "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

for( $i=0;$i<=8;++$i ){
    shuffle( $characters );
    $new_pass .= $characters[0];
}
```

Comment: and you don't get duplicate characters at all?

Comment: Or just: substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'), 0, 8) which would be cheaper.

Comment: @Alex - yes you do. @Leif - that is nicer you are right, thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about what particular values are in the array, you could try to implement a Linear Congruential Generator to generate all the values in the array.

[LCG implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Wikipedia lists some values you can use, and the rules to select the values for the LCG algorithm, because the LCG algorith is deterministic it is guaranteed not to repeat a single value before the length of the period.

After filling the array with this unique numbers, you can simply get the numbers in the array 1 by 1 in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
$isShowCategory = array();
for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++) { 
   $myCategory = array_rand($arrTrCategoryApp,1); 
   if (!in_array($myCategory, $isShowCategory)) {
      $isShowCategory[] = $myCategory;

      #do something 

   }
}
```

Comment: adding some context around your answer (eg why it solves the problem) would help other people looking at the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Easy and clean:

```
$colors = array('blue', 'green', 'orange');
$history = $colors;

function getColor($colors, &$history){
    if(count($history)==0)
        $history = $colors;
    return array_pop( $history );
}

echo getColor($colors, $history);
```